# After form sending Email I recieve just data from input fields, when transition Javascript scripts active

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I had tried different variations of this trouble solution, but in result just text inputs sent to email, but elements with "wpforms-selected" class don't send, when nextformspage.js scripts active on website and everything goes wrong. This scripts active on website https://staging-new.deutsche-thermo.de/mobile-heizung-lp-2/ , which have developed on wordpress. In this case I can edit just forms.js, nextformspage.js and functions.php files. So how can I fix this codes and error in website?

Here is last version of forms.js file in website

```
const wpForm = document.querySelector('.lindenfield-step-form-v1');
const choiceItems = document.querySelectorAll('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-image-choices-item');
const wpformsPage = document.querySelectorAll('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-page');
const wpformsLastPage = document.querySelectorAll('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-page.last.wpform-footer-btns');
const wpformButtonNext = document.querySelectorAll('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-page-next');
const wpformButtonBack = document.querySelectorAll('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-page-prev');
const wpformsButtonSubmit = document.querySelector('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-submit');
const wpformsFields = document.querySelectorAll('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-field');
const wpformsTextFields = document.querySelectorAll('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-field.wpforms-field-text');
const wpformsRequiredField = document.querySelectorAll('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-field-required');
const wpformsIndicatorWrap = document.querySelector('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-page-indicator-page-progress-wrap');
const wpformsIndicatorProgress = document.querySelector('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-page-indicator-page-progress');
const wpformsIndicatorContainer = document.createElement('div');
wpformsIndicatorContainer.className = 'wpforms-page-indicator-container';
wpformsIndicatorProgress.appendChild(wpformsIndicatorContainer);
const wpformsIndicatorText = document.createElement('div');
wpformsIndicatorText.className = 'wpforms-page-indicator-text';
wpformsIndicatorContainer.appendChild(wpformsIndicatorText);
const wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth = Math.round(parseFloat(wpformsIndicatorProgress.style.width));
wpformsIndicatorText.innerText = wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth + '% geschaft';
//current page index
let currentPageIndex = 0;

for (var item = 0; item < choiceItems.length; item++) {
    const choiceItemOnHover = document.createElement('div');
    choiceItemOnHover.className = "wpforms-choices-header-onhover";
    const label = choiceItems[item].querySelector('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-image-choices-label');
    choiceItemOnHover.innerText = label ? label.innerText : '';
    choiceItems[item].append(choiceItemOnHover);
}

showButton();

function showButton() {
    wpformButtonNext.forEach((button, index) => {
        const page = wpformsPage[index];
        if (page.getAttribute('data-page')) {
            const selectedItems = page.querySelectorAll(`.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-image-choices-item.wpforms-selected`);
            if (selectedItems.length === 0) {
                button.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else {
                button.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        } else {
            button.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    });
}

function progressNext() {
    const totalPages = wpformsPage.length;
    currentPageIndex = Array.from(wpformsPage).indexOf(this.closest('.lindenfield-step-form-v1 .wpforms-page'));

    if (currentPageIndex === totalPages - 2 || currentPageIndex === totalPages - 1) {
        const actualPercentValue = '95%';
        wpformsIndicatorProgress.style.width = actualPercentValue;
        wpformsIndicatorText.innerText = wpformsIndicatorProgress.style.width + ' - Fastgeschafft';
        wpformsIndicatorText.setAttribute('data-progress-width', wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth);
        /* const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
        if (screenWidth <= 768) {
            wpformsIndicatorText.style.right = '-20px';
        } else {
            wpformsIndicatorText.style.right = '-40px';
        } */
        wpForm.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

    } else {
        const pixelProgressWidth = window.getComputedStyle(wpformsIndicatorProgress).getPropertyValue('width');
        const currentIndicatorWidth = window.getComputedStyle(wpformsIndicatorWrap).getPropertyValue('width');
        const percentageValue = Math.round((parseFloat(pixelProgressWidth) / parseFloat(currentIndicatorWidth)) * 100);
        const actualPercentValue = wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth + percentageValue;
        wpformsIndicatorText.innerText = actualPercentValue + '% geschafft';
        wpformsIndicatorText.setAttribute('data-progress-width', wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth);
    }
    showButton();
    buttonDetect();
}

function progressBack() {
    const pixelProgressWidth = window.getComputedStyle(wpformsIndicatorProgress).getPropertyValue('width');
    const currentIndicatorWidth = window.getComputedStyle(wpformsIndicatorWrap).getPropertyValue('width');
    const percentageValue = Math.round((parseFloat(pixelProgressWidth) / parseFloat(currentIndicatorWidth)) * 100);
    const actualPercentValue = wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth - percentageValue;
    wpformsIndicatorText.innerText = -actualPercentValue + '% geschafft';
    showButton();
}

function addSelected(event) {
    const clickedChoiceItem = event.currentTarget;
    const currentPage = clickedChoiceItem.closest('.wpforms-page');
    const choiceItemsOnPage = currentPage.querySelectorAll('.wpforms-image-choices-item');
    choiceItemsOnPage.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('wpforms-selected'));
    clickedChoiceItem.classList.add('wpforms-selected');
    progressNext.call(clickedChoiceItem);
}

if (choiceItems) {

    for (var i = 0; i < wpformButtonNext.length; i++) {
        wpformButtonNext[i].addEventListener('click', progressNext);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < wpformButtonBack.length; i++) {
        wpformButtonBack[i].addEventListener('click', progressBack);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < choiceItems.length; i++) {
        choiceItems[i].addEventListener('click', addSelected);
    }

} else {
    console.error('wpformButtonNext not found');
}

wpformsButtonSubmit.innerText = 'Angebote erhalten';

function checkFields(page) {
    const textFields = page.querySelectorAll('.wpforms-field.wpforms-field-text input');
    const requiredFields = page.querySelectorAll('.wpforms-field-required input');

    let anyFieldEmpty = false;

    textFields.forEach((field) => {
        if (field.value.trim() === '') {
            anyFieldEmpty = true;
        }
    });

    requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
        if (field.value.trim() === '') {
            anyFieldEmpty = true;
        }
    });

    if (anyFieldEmpty === true) {
        wpformsButtonSubmit.disabled = true;
    } else {
        wpformsButtonSubmit.disabled = false;
    }

}

function buttonDetect() {
    if (wpformsButtonSubmit) {
        if (currentPageIndex < wpformsPage.length - 1) {
            const nextPage = wpformsPage[currentPageIndex + 1];

            nextPage.addEventListener('input', () => checkFields(nextPage));

            checkFields(nextPage);
        } else {
            console.log('No next page found');
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    
    if (screenWidth <= 768) {
        if (wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth <= 20) {
            wpformsIndicatorText.style.right = '-100px';
            wpformsIndicatorText.innerText = wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth + '% geschafft';
        } else if (wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth >= 20) {
            console.log("s17");
            wpformsIndicatorText.style.right = '-75px';
        } else if (wpformsIndicatorProgressWidth >= 80) {
            wpformsIndicatorText.style.right = '-20px';
        }
    }


    const firmaInput = document.querySelector('.wpforms-input-firma');
    const nameInput = document.querySelector('.wpforms-input-name');
    const plzInput = document.querySelector('.wpforms-input-plz');
    const phoneInput = document.querySelector('.wpforms-input-telefon');
    const errorText = document.querySelector('.wpforms-error');

    // Till here everything is okay

    function validateFirmaInput() {
        const maxLength = 39;
        const trimmedValue = trimInputValue(firmaInput);

        if (trimmedValue.length > maxLength) {
            firmaInput.value = trimmedValue.slice(0, maxLength);
        } else {
            const sanitizedValue = trimmedValue.replace(/[^A-Za-z()\s]/g, '');
            firmaInput.value = sanitizedValue;
        }
    }

    function validateNameInput() {
        const maxLength = 39;
        const trimmedValue = trimInputValue(nameInput);

        if (trimmedValue.length > maxLength) {
            nameInput.value = trimmedValue.slice(0, maxLength);
        }

        const sanitizedValue = trimmedValue.replace(/[^A-Za-z()\s]/g, '');
        nameInput.value = sanitizedValue;
    }

    function validatePlzInput() {
        const value = trimInputValue(plzInput);
        const sanitizedValue = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

        if (sanitizedValue.length > 5) {
            plzInput.value = sanitizedValue.slice(0, 5);
        } else {
            plzInput.value = sanitizedValue;
        }
    }

    function validatePhoneInput() {
        const value = trimInputValue(phoneInput);
        const maxLength = 17;

        if (value.length > maxLength) {
            phoneInput.value = value.slice(0, maxLength);
        }
    }

    firmaInput.addEventListener('input', validateFirmaInput);
    nameInput.addEventListener('input', validateNameInput);
    plzInput.addEventListener('input', validatePlzInput);
    phoneInput.addEventListener('input', validatePhoneInput);

    nameInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        const charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode;
        const allowedChars = /[A-Za-z()\s]/;
        const char = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

        if (!char.match(allowedChars)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    plzInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        const charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode;
        const allowedChars = /[0-9]/;
        const char = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

        if (!char.match(allowedChars)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    phoneInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        const charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode;
        const allowedChars = /[0-9,*+()\-_\s]/;
        const char = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        if (!char.match(allowedChars)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    function trimInputValue(input) {
        if (input && input.value) {
            return input.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        }
        return '';
    }

    function checkFields(page) {
        const textFields = page.querySelectorAll('.wpforms-field.wpforms-field-text input');
        const requiredFields = page.querySelectorAll('.wpforms-field-required input');

        let anyFieldEmpty = false;

        textFields.forEach((field) => {
            if (field.value.trim() === '') {
                anyFieldEmpty = true;
            }
        });

        requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
            if (field.value.trim() === '') {
                anyFieldEmpty = true;
            }
        });

        const isValidName = validateNameInput();
        const isValidFirma = validateFirmaInput();
        const isValidPlz = validatePlzInput();
        const isValidPhone = validatePhoneInput();

        if (anyFieldEmpty === true || !isValidName || !isValidFirma || !isValidPlz || !isValidPhone) {
            wpformsButtonSubmit.disabled = true;
        } else {
            wpformsButtonSubmit.disabled = false;
        }
    }

    wpformsPage.forEach(function (page) {
        page.addEventListener('input', () => checkFields(page));
    });

    // Initialize field validation on page load
    checkFields(wpformsPage[0]);
});
```

And here is nextformspage.js file, where had wrotten scripts for transition

```
var isClickAllowed = true;

function addTransitionClass() {
    wpformsPage.forEach(function (page) {
        page.classList.add("anim-trans");
    });

    wpformsIndicatorProgress.classList.add("anim-bar");

    setTimeout(function () {
        wpformsPage.forEach(function (page) {
            page.classList.remove("anim-trans");
        });
        wpformsIndicatorProgress.classList.remove("anim-bar");
    }, 1000);
}

choiceItems.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (isClickAllowed) {
            isClickAllowed = false;
            var closestPage = item.closest('.wpforms-page');
            var nextPageButton = closestPage.querySelector('.wpforms-page-next');
            nextPageButton.click();
            addTransitionClass();
            setTimeout(function () {
                isClickAllowed = true;
            }, 100);
        }
    });
});

function handleButtonClick(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (isClickAllowed) {
            isClickAllowed = false;
            addTransitionClass();
            setTimeout(function () {
                isClickAllowed = true;
            }, 100);
        }
    });
}

choiceItems.forEach(function (item) {
    handleButtonClick(item);
});

wpformButtonNext.forEach(function (item) {
    handleButtonClick(item);
});

wpformButtonBack.forEach(function (item) {
    handleButtonClick(item);
});
```

```
<?php
/**
 * GeneratePress.
 *
 * @package GeneratePress
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

require_once('session.php');
require_once('tracking.php');
require_once('lead.php');
require_once('regional.php');
require_once('wpsl.php');
require_once('regional_sitemap.php');

/*
 * Add Actions
 */
remove_action('wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7);
remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles');
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'fg1_dequeue_scripts', 100);
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'fg1_dequeue_styles', 100);
add_action('wp_head', 'fg1_ajax_url_nonce');

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_styles_and_scripts');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'forms_scripts');

add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', function () {
    wp_enqueue_style('local-fonts', "/wp-content/themes/generatepress-child/style.css", false, '1.0', 'all');
});


//login cookie secure
add_action('init', 'lf_wp_login_cookie_secure', 10);
function lf_wp_login_cookie_secure()
{

    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-login.php') !== false) {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['lm_wp_login_secure']) or $_COOKIE['lm_wp_login_secure'] != "TSvrEQHnzVaoriNmM5Sb") {
            header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
            exit();
        }
    }
}

function custom_enqueue_styles_and_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', '/wp-content/themes/generatepress-child/style.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}

function forms_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('nextformpage-js', '/wp-content/themes/generatepress-child/nextformpage.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('forms-js', '/wp-content/themes/generatepress-child/forms.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}

/**
 * Modify the required field indicator
 *
 * @link https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-change-required-field-indicator/
 */
 
 function wpf_dev_required_indicator( $text ) {
 
    return ' <span class="wpforms-required-label">' . __( ' ', 'wpforms' ) . '</span>';
}
 
add_filter( 'wpforms_get_field_required_label', 'wpf_dev_required_indicator', 10, 1 );

//End Modify

function fg1_dequeue_scripts()
{
    $wp_scripts = wp_scripts();
    if (isset($wp_scripts->registered['lazyload-youtube-js'])) {
        $wp_scripts->registered['lazyload-youtube-js']->src = '/wp-content/themes/generatepress-child/lazyload-youtube.js';
    }
}

function fg1_dequeue_styles()
{
    //wp_dequeue_style( 'aawp-styles' );
}

function fg1_ajax_url_nonce()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>';
        var ajaxnonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("itr_ajax_nonce"); ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
}


/** 
 * Removes empty paragraph tags from shortcodes in WordPress.
 */
function tg_remove_empty_paragraph_tags_from_shortcodes_wordpress($content)
{
    $toFix = array(
        '<p>[' => '[',
        ']</p>' => ']',
        ']<br />' => ']'
    );
    return strtr($content, $toFix);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'tg_remove_empty_paragraph_tags_from_shortcodes_wordpress');

function set_cache_value($cache_key, $cache_value)
{

    global $wpdb;

    $cache_value_db = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT cache_value FROM fg1_cache WHERE cache_key = %s LIMIT 1;", array($cache_key)));

    if (!empty($cache_value_db)) {
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE fg1_cache SET cache_value = '" . $cache_value . "' WHERE cache_key = %s LIMIT 1;", array($cache_key)));
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert('fg1_cache', array("cache_key" => $cache_key, "cache_value" => $cache_value));
    }
}

function get_cache_value($cache_key)
{

    global $wpdb;

    $ret = false;
    $cache_value = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT cache_value FROM fg1_cache WHERE cache_key = %s LIMIT 1;", array($cache_key)));
    if (!empty($cache_value))
        $ret = $cache_value->cache_value;

    return $ret;
}

add_action('init', 'custom_lazyload_youtube_proxy', 10, 0);
function custom_lazyload_youtube_proxy()
{

    global $wp;

    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/ythumb/') !== false) {
        $src = $_GET['src'];
        if (substr($src, 0, 23) == 'https://i2.ytimg.com/vi') {
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            readfile($src);
        }
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'custom_rest_api_init');

function custom_rest_api_init()
{

    register_rest_route(
        'lc/v1',
        '/get_all_wpforms/',
        array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_all_wpforms'
        )
    );

}

function get_all_wpforms()
{

    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'wpforms'
    );

    $wpforms_posts = get_posts($args);

    return $wpforms_posts;
}
function display_year()
{
    $year = date('Y');
    return $year;
}
add_shortcode('year', 'display_year');

add_shortcode('month', 'display_month');

function display_month()
{
    $monatsnamen = array(
        1 => "Januar",
        2 => "Februar",
        3 => "März",
        4 => "April",
        5 => "Mai",
        6 => "Juni",
        7 => "Juli",
        8 => "August",
        9 => "September",
        10 => "Oktober",
        11 => "November",
        12 => "Dezember"
    );
    $monat = date('n');
    return $monatsnamen[$monat];
}

function add_search_box($items, $args)
{
    $items .= '<li>' . get_search_form(false) . '</li>';
    return $items;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_topmenue_items', 'add_search_box', 10, 2);

add_filter('generate_search_placeholder', 'test_suche');
function test_suche()
{
    return 'Wonach suchen Sie?';
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'SearchFilter');
function SearchFilter($query)
{
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post__not_in', array(2, 129, 288, 425, 432, 594, 710, 885, 892, 1027, 1068, 1078, 1081, 1237, 1230, 1308, 1310, 1362, 1364, 1433, 2498, 3412, 3415, 3417, 3420, 3422, 3424, 4037, 7234, 7236, 7272, 7283, 7298, 7240, 7505, 7695, 8480, 8939, 9562, 10632, 10691, 10702, 10713, 10730, 10763, 10771, 10799, 10805, 10817, 10821, 10824, 10830, 10834, 10857, 11316, 11424, 11432, 11434, 12331));
    }

    return $query;
}

function limit_author_posts_per_page($query)
{
    if ($query->is_author()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 6);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_author_posts_per_page');

//WPforms Spam Schutz Token Gültigkeit erhöhen, sodass das Formular länger gecached und mit Spam-Schutz funktioniert
add_filter('wpforms_form_token_check_before_today', 'lf_wpforms_form_token_check_before_today');
function lf_wpforms_form_token_check_before_today($valid_token_times_before)
{
    $valid_token_times_before = [];
    $valid_days_ago = 100;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $valid_days_ago; $i++) {
        $valid_token_times_before[] = ($i * 86400);
    }

    return $valid_token_times_before;
}

function last_modified_shortcode()
{
    $date_format = 'd.m.Y';
    $last_modified = get_the_modified_date($date_format);
    return $last_modified;
}
add_shortcode('last_modified', 'last_modified_shortcode');
```

I want solve this problem, and in result recieve data from all elements with 'wpforms-selected' class in email

Comment: You added too mush code to your question and left out, maybe the most important, the HTML code for the form. Can you remove all the code that is not related to the issue and then add some of the HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't add all HTML code, because this is not functions correctly in website